# IIS7 - How do I use the same physical path for different domains?

Tags: iis-7, path, dns

I have two domains:
**principal.com
copy.com**

When someone type copy.com I want the user to see principal.com contents but whithout redirecting him to that domain.

Also if I create a subdomain such as **sub.copy.com it will show the content from principal.com**. Again, without redirect the user to that domain.

I tried configurating the DNS of copy.com to point to the same IP address of principal.com But **I don't know how to configure this domain in IIS7 for use the same physical path as principal.com or If I need to do some other task**...

I have done this with apache and the vhost files. Pointing multiple domains to the same DocumentRoot and configurating the DNS to use the same IP ADDRESS... But with IIS7 I don't know how to do it...

How Can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add multiple host headers to the web site (one for each domain), IIS should be able to serve up the same content for both requests.

To do this, click on the site in IIS, in the right hand panel ("Actions"), click on "Bindings..." and there you should be able to enter the different host names.

Comment: When I trid to do that The site get stopped because iis says there's a binding problem. I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: What are the values that you're entering (port, type, etc)? I can't think of why it would say that there was a binding issue, as we do this quite frequently. Are there any other bindings that exist on the site, or are there any other sites that maybe have the same bindings that are causing an issue?

Comment: Also, in the system logs, is there an actual error message (maybe that has a code) that is being logged when the site stops?

Comment: Thanks in advanced chris, I'm starting with iis7.

I have the domain principal.com with this bindings:
http | www.principal.com | 80 | 183.201.16.246

What I do after reading your answer was try to configure a binding for copy.com like this:
http | www.principal.com | 80 | 183.201.16.246

But it says I cant do that because this binding is already in use...

Comment: Ah, I think I might know what's going on - https usually uses port 443 and http uses port 80, see if changing the port on that mapping to 443 helps at all.

Comment: By the way. Do I have to change the Application Pool for copy.com to use the same application pool as principal.com?

Comment: when adding the binding for copy.com, can you enter it as: http | www.copy.com | 80 | 183.201.16.246, or do you receive an error with that as well?

Comment: Since you'll be using the same web site for both bindings, I don't think it can be split into two app pools, so you won't have to worry about that.

Comment: Yes, But I tried using a different port (81) and It works... Now when I type copy.com in the browser it asks me for user and password...

Comment: If I don't change the Application Pool I receive this error: The path does not exist or environment variables in the path could not be expanded to verify whether it exists. This error is for copy.com domain...

Comment: Do you have seperate web sites in IIS for copy.com and principle.com, or just one web site? (My apologies on having to do all of this in comments, it looks like stackoverflow won't let me open a chat because I don't have enough points yet)

Comment: Dont worry, it's the same for me (cant chat). I have to entries in the "Sites Tree" One for each domain.

Comment: Can you try using one entry for both (since they'll be accessing the same files)? And can you also add bindings for both sites on that one entry and test?

Comment: Oh This is fantastic. Now I can see the same content for both domains :) Just one more thing: How can I see the same content when I type subdomain.copy.com? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. I think for the subdomain, you'd approach it the same way by adding another host entry to that one web site (e.g., http | subdomain.copy.com | 80 | [the IP address]).

Comment: I have already done that but it's not displaying at all. I think it's a DNS topic so maybe I will open another question. Thanks Chris for your support :)